# Error opening feature class of geodatabase in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase

I have a problem. Whenever I try to create, edit or delete feature classes in ArcGIS geodatabase it gives me an following error: "Error opening feature class." and "Could not add the specified data object to the map."

When I try to open it with QGIS (2.10.1) it is entirely ok and I can even export it as a shapefile and then open it in the ArcMap and it is ok aswell. I have been searching on the internet a lot but I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem anywhere.

I should probably add that it happens with **EVERY geodatabase**, even if I create a brand new one so I don't think its because the databases are corrupted; also I am using ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced with a school license (verisons 10.3.1 and 10.2.2).

[image: Some errors I am getting]

Comment: It sounds like your file geodatabase has been corrupted for geodatabase behavior.  QGIS uses one of two potential libraries, neither of which is geodatabase aware.  Please **edit** the question to specify the version of QGIS and whether you are using the Esri or open access library.  If ArcGIS says the geodatabase is corrupt, then it's in the best position to know; you may need make use of your dataset backup.

Comment: Are you able to view the feature classes in Catalog?

Comment: No I am not, it gives me the same error.

Comment: @Marian, what about the `default.gdb` - can you create and access files through it?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vince:

> It sounds like your file geodatabase has been corrupted for
>   geodatabase behavior. QGIS uses one of two potential libraries,
>   neither of which is geodatabase aware. Please edit the question to
>   specify the version of QGIS and whether you are using the Esri or open
>   access library. If ArcGIS says the geodatabase is corrupt, then it's
>   in the best position to know; you may need make use of your dataset
>   backup.

The GDB sounds corrupt. So long as you can still access the data within from QGIS I would export everything to a new GDB and delete the corrupt entity before the problem spreads.

Comment: Note that there's a lot that can be lost here: Topologies, Rasters, possibly Domains...  Passing the data though shapefile would be worse, but a good backup might be better still.

Comment: I don't thinks that it is because of the corrupted GDB because tha same happens when I create the new one. And also when I open files in ArcGIS we have in the school then it is OK. I think it is something with my computer but I have no clue what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ArcGIS BASIC, that license level does not support the use of subtypes if they are employed in your GDB. Another possibility is that your GDB could be corrupted if it was exported from an SDE schema, particularly one with complexities such as relationship tables, network topology, etc. Just some things to check.

Comment: I have edited my question. I am using Advanced version of ArcGIS and the same happens also when I create a new GDB. Also I am able to open the same files at school computers using ArcGIS just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wasn't able to find any solution so I have reinstalled the whole OS and it helped. Something was seriously wrong :D