# Unable to add shapefile. Receive an "Open Failed - Error Opening Feature Class" when trying to open in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, error

When I attempt to add a shapefile from a folder to my ArcMap document I receive this message.

Why am I unable to add this shapefile? I've looked around for a similar issue, however other posts deal with open error ["Getting “Failed to open tool” message when trying to run geoprocessing tool from C# code"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59654/getting-failed-to-open-tool-message-when-trying-to-run-geoprocessing-tool-from) or [Error opening feature class of geodatabase in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185843/error-opening-feature-class-of-geodatabase-in-arcgis-for-desktop) Don't really deal with my same issue.

Here is the message I receive:

[image]

All of the files and folders are in the same format and accessible the same way.

[image]

All the extensions are available and don't appear to be corrupt in anyway.

[image]

Here my shapefile icon displays black question mark in a green box.

[image]

Here are all the files in ArcMap except for the "glpv1" shapefile

[image]

When I open the file using QGIS, it displays and works just fine.

[image]

Comment: do you have the .dbf file?

Comment: apparently not, that's seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Related to my comment, the minimum files to make up a shapefile are the .dbf, .shx, and .shp (.prj is nice to have too).  You are missing the **glpv1.dbf** file.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a simple *.dbf file with Python as follows:

```
import shapefile # pyshp
import dbf
import os.path

fn_shp = "glpv1.shp"
myshp = open(fn_shp, "rb")

# If dbf does not exist, create one
fn_dbf = os.path.splitext(fn_shp)[0] + ".dbf"
if not os.path.exists(fn_dbf):
    r = shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp)
    n = len(r.shapes())
    db = dbf.Table(fn_dbf, 'ID N(8,0);')
    with db:
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            db.append((i,))
    r.close()
```